# Animate Tabs in TabLayout

Tags: android, android-animation, android-custom-view, android-tablayout

To be specific I want to **animate the tabs** and **not the ViewPager fragments**.

I am having trouble deciding **how to build this**. Whether to use a **separate scrollview** or this can be achieved with **TabLayout with some customizations**.

[image: This is the goal]

> Goal

1. Change the size of tab based on selection.
2. Change the size of tab based on position.

My idea is to use custom tabs & change the size using `TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener` methods `onTabSelected` & `onTabUnselected`. But I would like to know if there is any direct approach to get this effect. For example, parallax effect in CollapsingToolbar.

Comment: I've edited the question. Check the gif @Rahul